# How to handle multiple shots with different directions in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am programming a game with libGDX. The protagonist can shoot at some flying enemies.
Heres my problem:
I don't know how I can handle multiple shots at the same time. Here is my code:

```
    private Image backgroundImage = new Image(backgroundTexture);
    private Stage levelStage = new Stage(), menuStage = new Stage();
    private Table menuTable = new Table();
    private Skin menuSkin = Manager.menuSkin;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Rectangle farmer, ufo;
    private Array<Rectangle> lasers;
    private boolean ufoMovementLeft = true;
    private boolean leftArrow = false;
    private boolean rightArrow = false;
    private float laserMovement[] = new float[100];
    private int ufoLife = 15;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        levelStage.addActor(backgroundImage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(levelStage);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        farmer = new Rectangle();
        farmer.x = 480 / 2 - 56 / 2; farmer.y = 80;
        farmer.width = 55; farmer.height = 140;

        ufo = new Rectangle();
        ufo.x = 500 / 2; ufo.y = 600;
        ufo.width = 160; ufo.height = 70;

        lasers = new Array<Rectangle>();
    }

    public void spawnLaser() {
        Rectangle laser = new Rectangle();
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
             lasers.add(laser);
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
             laserMovement[lasers.size] = touchPos.x;
             camera.unproject(touchPos);
             laser.x = farmer.x + 50; laser.y = 110;
             laser.width = 25; laser.height = 20;
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         camera.update();
         levelStage.act();
         levelStage.draw();

         batch.setProjectionMatrix(levelStage.getCamera().combined);
         batch.begin();
         movement();
         if(leftArrow) {if(farmer.x >= 50) farmer.x -= 2; 
batch.draw(farmerLeftTexture, farmer.x, farmer.y);}
         else if(rightArrow) {if(farmer.x <= 370) farmer.x += 2; 
batch.draw(farmerRightTexture, farmer.x, farmer.y);}
         else batch.draw(farmerBackTexture, farmer.x, farmer.y);
         if(ufoMovementLeft) {ufo.x -= 1; 
if(ufo.x < 50) ufoMovementLeft = false; } 
             else {ufo.x += 1; if(ufo.x > 300) ufoMovementLeft = true ; } 
         batch.draw(ufoTexture, ufo.x, ufo.y);
         if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) spawnLaser();
         Iterator<Rectangle> iter = lasers.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
               Rectangle laser = iter.next();
               laser.y += 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
               laser.x += (laserMovement[lasers.size] - farmer.x + farmer.x * 0.25) * 2 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
               if(laser.overlaps(ufo)){iter.remove(); ufoLife -= 1;}
               if(laser.y + 64 > 550) iter.remove();
            }
         for(Rectangle laser: lasers) {
             batch.draw(laserTexture, laser.x, laser.y);
         }
```

The problem at this point is that the shots are handled "as if they were one". If the player shoots in a different direction than the other shots before, every bullet that is on the screen at the moment changes its direction.
I just have no idea how to solve this problem, so every help is appreciated :).
Cheers, Joshflux

EDIT: I edited the code, and here are some screenshots: 
The [first](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=b1978a-1445166753.png) one shows to shots fired to the left side, but in the [second](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=df9d14-1445166795.png) one you can see that after i fired two shots to the right side, the first two shots also start to move to the right.

Comment: Could you please only post the relevant code? And format your code, so that the if statement body is on the next line, it is quite hard to read that.

Comment: could you add some screenshots? it is not clear what you mean by ' the shots are handled "as if they were one" '

Comment: Allright, did it :).

Comment: You have problem in the line where you add value to laser.x.  You use the laserMovement of last laser for all iterations over iter. Two solutions: 1. Introduce counter in that loop, 2. Refactor code a little and store Rectangle and movement in new class and add those to the array